# Solution to kind of Vandermonde system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Is there a closed-form solution for $c$ in the equation $Ac = b$, where $A$, $c$, $b$ respectively are the below matrices and $n \in Z^+$?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
    0       & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \frac{1}{n} \\
    0 & 1 & (\frac{1}{2})^2 & (\frac{1}{3})^2 & \dots & (\frac{1}{n})^2 \\
    0 & 1 & (\frac{1}{2})^3 & (\frac{1}{3})^3 & \dots & (\frac{1}{n})^3 \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & 1 & (\frac{1}{2})^n & (\frac{1}{3})^n & \dots & (\frac{1}{n})^n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
c_0 \\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \\ \vdots \\ c_n
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
    f(0) \\ f'(0) \\ f''(0) \\ f^{(3)}(0) \\ \vdots \\ f^{(n)}(0)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I recognize that there's a Vandermonde matrix inside of $A$, but I'm not sure how to use that to get to a solution.

Sorry for the weird formatting, I can't figure out how to put them all on one line in the StackExchange format.

Comment: Hello @Mu Prime, welcome to MSE. Always use double dollar signs to put an equation on a single line, like so: \$\$ <equation> \$\$. A tutorial on how to typeset equations with MathJax can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Ernie060 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition the matrix, $$M=\begin{bmatrix}A&B\\C&D\end{bmatrix}$$ where $A=1$ and $D$ is the Vandermonde matrix. Then you can express the inverse of $M$ using the formula in [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement?wprov=sfti1), which requires the inversion of the Schur’s complement, $A-BD^{-1}C$, which is just 1, and the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix $D$, which has this [formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix).

Note that I would not recommend doing this in floating point arithmetic because of poor conditioning of $D$ and $M$ itself.